# horizontal centering 4 Div's inside a Div

Tags: html, css

I need to create a small portfolio for school, at the top I want to create a menu with 4 categories (see picture).

http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160206/ixtj8mtk.jpg

Basically I have created a "main" div (100% width) and inside this main div I created 4 boxes, now I need to put the 4 divs next to each other and center them inside the main div, but I can't get it to work, atm it is centered but the 4 divs are on top of each other instead of left/right to each other.

```css
.mainmenu {
 background-color: grey;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 min-height: 50px;
 float: left;
}

.mainbox {
 background-color: grey;
 width: 100px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 min-height: 30px;
 float: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  
 .mainbox {
 background-color: #DABA11;
 width: 200px;
 font-style: italic;
 }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Portfolio</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body style="text-align: center;">

<div class="mainmenu">

 <div class="mainbox"> 
    WHAT
    </div>
    
    <div class="mainbox">
    WHO
    </div>
    
   <div class="mainbox">
    WHEN
    </div>
    
    <div class="mainbox">
    WHY
    </div>  
    
    
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you should have researched your question before putting it up here. See [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=put%20divs%20next%20to%20each%20other%20horizontally&oq=put%20divs%20next%20to%20each%20other&rlz=1CAHPZY_enUS656US656&ie=UTF-8&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.5331j0j7&sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.&bvm=bv.113370389,d.cWw&biw=1366&bih=677&dpr=1&ech=1&psi=Pjy2VuGJGcTk-AH-sYXYCw.1454783551508.3&ei=Pjy2VuGJGcTk-AH-sYXYCw&emsg=NCSR&noj=1&surl=1&gws_rd=ssl&safe=active&ssui=on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/lalu050/zxz0mo2e/1/show/)

see the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/zxz0mo2e/1/)

Change your CSS a bit as follows

```
.mainmenu {
    background-color: grey;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.mainbox {
    background-color: grey;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 30px;
    float: none;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

By default, a div has a `display:block` style which forces the divs to a new line.Thus, what I have done is, added `text-align: center;` instead of `float:left` for `.mainmenu` and added `display:inline-block;` for `.mainbox` which forces the divs to be inline.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to acomplish what You want, easiest one is to use flexbox. Just add `display: flex;` to `.mainmenu` class.

Answer (score 0):

Make inner divs inline-block elements with set width:

```
.mainmenu {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

.mainbox {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason the divs are stacked on top of each other is for 1 main reason.

A div is a block element. This means that by default its CSS is set to `display:block;`

To fix this, just add css for each div to `display:inline-block;` or `display:inline;`